# Unity Loading Image?

Tags: unity

I have a quastion about loading screen in unity. I don't want to make a scene between to levels [Main Menu > Loading Scene > Game level]. I want to use Canvas "Image"that run at the start of the game level and then disappear after few seconds [Main Menu > Game level]. Is this good idea ?

Comment: what do you do in Loading Scene?

Comment: A Loading screen or scene is a scene use to give time for game level to be loaded. [http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/SarahHerzog/20151125/260053/Creating_an_Animating_Loading_Screen_in_Unity_5.php]

Comment: Yes, this could be a good idea. Is that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a Main Menu canvas to exist in your level and disable/destroy it when you're done with it. So just do exactly that in the OnClick handler of your button(s).

```
public void OnClick()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Have the above in a script attached to your menu canvas' object and select it as the method to call for your button's OnClick.

Now, if you want this to happen automatically after, say, 5 seconds...

```
float delay = 5f;
float timer = 0f;
private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer >= delay)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

There are much better and more concise ways to handle delayed actions like this, but this should demonstrate things adequately.

Comment: Probably the most simple way you will find to do it, i actually like this method allot. +1 for you! I was trying to think of the most complex way, that actually causes objects to load in stages to allow for everything to load properly, but this works way better haha.